# How to ignore hidden files using os.listdir()?

Tags: python, hidden-files

My python script executes an `os.listdir(path)` where the path is a queue containing archives that I need to treat one by one.

The problem is that I'm getting the list in an array and then I just do a simple `array.pop(0)`. It was working fine until I put the project in subversion. Now I get the `.svn` folder in my array and of course it makes my application crash.

So here is my question: is there a function that ignores hidden files when executing an `os.listdir()` and if not what would be the best way?

Comment: you may also want to avoid folders with `os.path.isdir()`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can write one yourself:

```
import os

def listdir_nohidden(path):
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            yield f
```

Or you can use a [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
import os

def listdir_nohidden(path):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*'))
```

Either of these will ignore all filenames beginning with `'.'`.

Comment: the proposed function `listdir_nohidden` is not quite compatible with `os.listdir`, since the use of `yield` makes it a generator. Instead it should run through the output list from `os.listdir` and remove entries that start with '.'

Comment: @0sh: Why does it have to remove things in-place? Just define a new function that does `list(listdir_nohidden(path))` and that new function is exactly compatible with `os.listdir`.

Comment: So in other words, there's no builtin regex in `listdir()` that allows you to customise your list.

Answer (score 74):

This is an old question, but seems like it is missing the obvious answer of using list comprehension, so I'm adding it here for completeness:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(path) if not f.startswith('.')]
```

As a side note, the docs state `listdir` will return results in 'arbitrary order' but a common use case is to have them sorted alphabetically. If you want the directory contents alphabetically sorted without regards to capitalization, you can use:

```
sorted((f for f in os.listdir() if not f.startswith(".")), key=str.lower)
```

(Edited to use `key=str.lower` instead of a `lambda`)

Comment: `key=lambda f: f.lower()` can be written without lambda: `key=str.lower`

Comment: To combine both:
`sorted([f for f in os.listdir('./') if not f.startswith('.')], key=str.lower)`

Answer (score 30):

On Windows, Linux and OS X:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import win32api, win32con


def folder_is_hidden(p):
    if os.name== 'nt':
        attribute = win32api.GetFileAttributes(p)
        return attribute & (win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN | win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
    else:
        return p.startswith('.') #linux-osx
```

Comment: should also work on a Mac, hidden files start there with '.' as well.

Comment: This is the only portable answer, great job, but the other answers provide a full wrapper for os.listdir so... `[f for f in os.listdir(path) if not folder_is_hidden(f)]`

Comment: Why do you check the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` flag too?  Are system files hidden by default on Windows?

Answer (score 19):

Joshmaker has the right solution to your question.
[How to ignore hidden files using os.listdir()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099290/how-to-ignore-hidden-files-using-os-listdir/26554941#26554941)

In Python 3 however, it is recommended to use pathlib instead of os.

```
from pathlib import Path 
visible_files = [
    file for file in Path(".").iterdir() if not file.name.startswith(".")
]
```

Answer (score 17):

[glob](http://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*')
```

(`glob` claims to use `listdir` and `fnmatch` under the hood, but it also checks for a leading `'.'`, not by using `fnmatch`.)

Answer (score 9):

I think it is too much of work to go through all of the items in a loop. I would prefer something simpler like this:

```
lst = os.listdir(path)
if '.DS_Store' in lst:
    lst.remove('.DS_Store')
```

If the directory contains **more than one hidden files**, then this can help:

```
all_files = os.popen('ls -1').read()
lst = all_files.split('\n')
```

for platform independence as @Josh mentioned the glob works well:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*')
```

Comment: That works only if you have _one_ hidden file, **and** you know the name of it. What if the directory contains dozens of hidden files, with arbitrary names that you can't know in advance?

Comment: Hi @FeRD, Yes. When I am doing batch/backlog processing on a mac, I put all the files in new folder and `.DS_Store` gets created automatically. When I zip all the files and push it to a server `.DS_Store` also gets added. If there are various hidden files then may be you can try `os.system('ls -1')`

Comment: Not cross-platform. `os.popen('ls -1').read()` won't work on Windows. That's the whole point of `os.listdir()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
filenames = (f.name for f in os.scandir() if not f.name.startswith('.'))
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can just use a simple for loop that will exclude any file or directory that has "." in the front.**

Code for professionals:

```py
import os

directory_things = [i for i in os.listdir() if i[0] != "."] # Exclude all with . in the start
```

Code for noobs

```py
items_in_directory = os.listdir()
final_items_in_directory = []

for i in items_in_directory:
    if i[0] != ".": # If the item doesn't have any '.' in the start
        final_items_in_directory.append(i)
```