# Ignoring specific files with `os.listdir`

Tags: python, macos

How can I change this python code to ignore Mac OS' .DS_Store files?

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()
```

Edit: This question looks a lot like this question ([How to ignore hidden files using os.listdir()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099290/how-to-ignore-hidden-files-using-os-listdir)) but I don't know how to implement that solution into the above class. I tried this:

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname) if not fname.startswith('.'):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.split()
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore hidden files using os.listdir()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099290/how-to-ignore-hidden-files-using-os-listdir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if-statement here by checking that the file name is not equal (`!=`) to "DS_Store":

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            if fname != '.DS_Store':
                for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                    yield line.split()
```

If the filename does equal this string, then that loop is simply passed-over without the nested `for` statement being touched.