# Python os.listdir() returns $RECYCLE.BIN

Tags: python, file

Using `os.listdir(pathname = root drive)` gives a list including `$RECYCLE.BIN` though its hidden. How can I exclude these hidden items?

I have found some thread on how not to show hidden ones. But in case of only `$RECYCLE.BIN` being hidden it doesn't seems to work.
Expecting something/ a way like `os.listdir()` which will return a list including only visible items.

Comment: "hidden files" are an OS concept, not something Python would know on its own.

Comment: Eg. You need to query the OS file attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063074/2308683

Comment: Have you tried `glob` to see if it operates differently?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the code, still not getting it. went over my head

Comment: @MarkRansom doesn't 'glob' needs to be specified which type of file i want to see? for example import glob
`import os
from os import path

def listdir_nohidden(path):
    return glob.glob(path+'*gif')

mypath = "D:/"

print(listdir_nohidden(mypath))`

Comment: Not getting that link? `import win32api` if you are using Windows, then you use file attribute flags of hidden or system file to check. Then you can filter those out from listdir (mentioned in the comments)

Comment: You can use `glob` with `*` or `**` to get everything.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried `glob` myself and it *does* include $RECYCLE.BIN too.

Comment: The code linked by @OneCricketeer should work fine, don't worry if it goes over your head - just copy it.